# Magento 2 Form Builder

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 Form Builder

Hello everyone,

I am looking for a powerful and easy-to-use Magento 2 Form Builder extension, could anyone here recommend me some extensions?

Thank you and I'm looking forward to hearing from you!

Answer (score 0):

I have used two form builder extensions until now 
1.Amasty Custom Form
https://amasty.com/custom-form-for-magento-2.html

I am using this module from Magento 2.1.7 and I have done two updates until now and the module and it's functionality seems to be good without any bugs during upgrade.

2. Land of coder

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-form-builder.html

Used this module too. Working fine but I have not done any upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

We have great experience with the Webforms extension of Mageme: https://mageme.com/webforms-custom-form-magento-2.html. It is highly customizable, supports multiple languages. Also support is great!